# What should content security policy header value to redirect back to applcation, after Azure OIDC logout

Tags: azure-active-directory, http-headers, content-security-policy, response-headers

I have Web application, uses Azure OIDC for login. with response headers set for web pages as

```
content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://login.microsoftonline.com;
```

With above header, after successful Azure Logout, browser stays in the Azure page only and doesn't redirect back to Original applciation.

Azure Success Logout Url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX/oauth2%2Flogout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww2.test.me.net%2F%23%2Fsignout

But without

```
content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://login.microsoftonline.com;
```

in the response header for webpages, it works fine,
So what should be header value to work with header as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   According to the Azure OIDC app authentication configuration and user flow structure, the header values are configured to redirect the user flow in browser to a particular page according to the policy defined for the Azure OIDC app. Thus, the content security policy header for successful logout action according to the policy designed by you for your Azure OIDC app should be the initial application login page or home page.

•   Please find the sample content security policy header for logout step in Azure OIDC web app: -

```
   ‘ content-security-policy: frame-ancestors script-src ‘self’ 
      https://<webappname>.azurewebsites.net; ’
```

Also, please note that if no website is stated in the logout header for content security policy, the default-src header applies that will redirect the application in the browser to the main application home page and serves as a fallback for other CSP fetch directives as in the default-src directive, the redirect URI of the application webpage is stated.

•   Thus, the header value should be as mentioned above by replacing the response URI or link stated there with your application page URI.

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-security-headers

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect

Answer (score 0):

`'self'` always initiated from the Url from the browser address bar (by tuple of scheme://hostname:port_number).
Looks like `'self'` token does not covers `www2.test.me.net` source, maybe because main page Url in the address is not match `www2.test.me.net`.

If you performs logout redirect inside iframe, you have to add exact redirect location (`https://www2.test.me.net`) into frame-ancestors:

```
content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://login.microsoftonline.com https://www2.test.me.net;
```

because after redirecting, the frame will actually be embedded in the page with the `https://www2.test.me.net` Url.

Comment: This didn't work out, one x-frame-optiions has been set to samorigin,is this creating a problem, suggest me possible value for this as well, it gets redirected from My applicaation to login.microsot.com and from theere it has to redirect,back to my application, so do  we need replace frame-ancestors, please suggest me on this. Also all works well, if content-security-policy is taken off,

Comment: (1) `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors` overrides `X-Frame-Optiions: samorigin` in all browsers except Safari. Plus, everything works when you remove CSP, so XFO has nothing to do with it. It's weird though. (2) Can you show a CSP message about blocking in the browser console - there should be a Url that is being blocked.